# Java enums insert values

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum created as below

```
public enum CustomData {

    SHOW_VAL("","");

    private final String valCode;
    private final String valD;  

    CustomData(String valCode, String valD){
        this.valCode = valCode;
        this.valD = valD;
    }

    public String getvalCode() {
        return this.valCode;
    }

    public String getvalD() {
        return this.valD;
    }   
}
```

I am throwing exception using the enum Custom Data. Right now, I can create multiple static types like `SHOW_VAL("TEXT","DESC")`, but I want to put the text in it at runtime when any error occurs.

In the above, code how can I insert the values via the constructor defined above in other class?

Comment: You can't catch an *error* in java. Do you mean exception?

Comment: Why you need `enum` for simple class?

Comment: How are you calling it? Can't you just pass in `exception.getXXX()` to your enum?

Comment: If you can't set the value in the constructor, you will need to set it after construction.

Answer (score 2):

Enums are a compile time constant, you can't create new ones in the runtime using regular language features. As per [Enum Type docs:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

> You should use enum types any time you need to represent a fixed set of constants. That includes natural enum types such as the planets in our solar system and data sets where you know all possible values at compile time—for example, the choices on a menu, command line flags, and so on.

Use a regular `class` for runtime values.